# @Html Action syntax to pass value of hidden input with id

Tags: jquery, html, razor, action

From my view(.cshtml) in the call below:

```
@Html.Action("MyActionName", "MyController", new { id = 1 })
```

id = 1 is currently hardcoded to 1 but I need to set id = the value of a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" id="MyId" />

//I've tested that "MyId" does have the correct value with:
    $(function () {
        $("#myButton").click(function () {
            var vid = $("#MyId").val()
            alert(vid);...
```

I can't seem to get the correct syntax for the `@Html.Action` call.

Thanks

Comment: So since this code is not static because the value of the hidden field can change I would append it to the statically typed url. Append it to the action call as JS and it should work. var myLinke='@Html.Action()&myParamHere='+$("#myID").val();

Comment: `$('a').attr('href','\mycontroller\myactionname?id='+vid)`

Comment: I'm using @Html.Action. There is no link. This is in a div in a view

    <div id="divMyActionName" style="display:none">
        @Html.Action("MyActionName", "MyController", new { id = 1 })
    </div>

Again, how can I replace 1 with the value in MyId. Thank you for your help.